# MVC Razor syntax displaying data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have following list returned to my razor view.

```
StudentName: Andy, Subject: Programming, Fee: 100
StudentName: Andy, Subject: Math, Fee: 200
StudentName: Andy, Subject: Chemistry, Fee: 300
StudentName: Mark, Subject: English, Fee: 400
```

I need to display above list on my view as following in tabular format with Andy and Mark showing as table header and other data as rows.

```
**Andy**
Programming 100
Math 200
Chemistry 300

**Mark**
English 400
```

I am trying as follow but it repeats Student name with each row

```
@model List <myModel>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.StudentName</td>
            <td>@item.Subject</td>
            <td>@item.Fee</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply group your data:

```
@foreach(var grow in Model.GroupBy(r=>r.StudentName))
{
  <tr><td colspan=2>@grow.Key</td></tr>
  foreach(var row in grow)
  {
    <tr><td>@row.Subject</td><td>@row.Fee</td></tr>
  }
}
```